# Contar una letra A dentro input y con un button

Tags: javascript

Buenas soy estudiante de Js y se que mi pregunta sera absurda pero llevo unos días haciendo un montón de ejercicios, y todo era un mar de placer hasta que me he atascado, y ahora mi mente ha entrado en bucle jajajaj.

intento hacer el típico contador de letra "A" y si le añado un botón no me sale,( mira la tontería pero es así.
Os dejo el código para que den luz a mi ceguera y cansancio!!

```js
 document.querySelector("#boton1").addEventListener('click', () => {
var cadena =  parseInt(document.querySelector('#frase').value);

var indices = [];
for(var i = 0; i < cadena.length; i++) {
    if (cadena[i].toLowerCase() === "a") indices.push(i);
}

document.querySelector("#resultado").innerHTML = indices.length;

});
```

```html
<textarea id="frase" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
<button id="boton1">
calcular
</button>
<div id="resultado"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pues claro, estás convirtiendo el texto a número sin razón.

```
var cadena = parseInt(document.querySelector('#frase').value);
```

debería ser:

```
var cadena = document.querySelector('#frase').value;
```

Comment: puffff, ves el cansancio me tiene machacado, gracias!!